# Need Help with Interpreting this Answer

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

[Generating Functions help](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/210404/generating-functions-help)

I'm not quite sure how to go from the reciprocal function to the coefficient of $x^{100}$; could anyone help me out?

I have an exam on this in 2 days, and I'm still extremely confused! Any help would be greatly appreciated. A friend suggested that i break things down into partial fractions, but I still don't see how to make the jump